# API: Querying TestCaseResults with project scoping?

Tags: rally

Is it possible to query for testcase results using project scoping?

The TestCaseResult object does not contain a project scope, and queries for testcaseresults seem to ignore project scoping.

So is there a way to, for example, to query for all test case results in the last 14 days scoped under a particular project and its children projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard WSAPI, you can do:

`((TestCase.Project.Name = "My Project") AND (CreationDate > "2013-01-07"))`

or

`((TestCase.Project.ObjectID = "12345678910") AND (CreationDate > "2013-01-07"))`

on TestCaseResults and it should provide you with Project-scoped TCR's.

If you desire child projects, you'd need to either run multiple queries, or do some complicated AND'ing.

Comment: Ok...so one query to get the project hierarchy OIDs... a second one with a complex query with all needed projects.  Annoying but doable I suppose since all results have test cases...